ROS Humble MoveIt2 - No Planning Library Loaded
I have been having some issues trying to install and use the MoveIt2 tutorials as listed here. I followed the entirety of the "Getting Started" instructions, and only installed the barebones ROS binaries (ros-humble-ros-base). I was able to complete the colcon build with seemingly no issues, but when I launch the MoveIt demo, the
MotionPlanning and PlanningScene displays both show warnings:

Additionall, under the Context tab of the MotionPlanning panel, it indicates there's no planning library loaded, and the dropdown menus are completely empty:

I'd previously had some issues even getting RViz to run with the MoveIt plugins, which led me to use the base install without the RViz binaries, as I believe the colcon build also builds RViz from source. I previously thought there might be a linking error against the RViz binaries.
I'm not entirely sure what next to look into, as I'm relatively new to both RViz and MoveIt. I've also copied the terminal output and uploaded it here: https://pastecode.io/s/7breuj80
Any feedback is appreciated!

I've got the same problem and have found a work-around. The problems lays in OMPL planner. Quick and dirty solution is just to remove it from launch file:
~/ws_moveit2/src/moveit2_tutorials/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/launch/demo.launch.py

line 32: pipelines=["ompl", "stomp", "pilz_industrial_motion_planner"]

Just delete "ompl" planner, rthe est should work fine.
Then build and source workspace
I am not planning to use ompl anyway so I don't know if I will investigate that further...
